# How many different 7 card hands are there that contain two or more cards of the same rank?

Tags: combinatorics

**Answer:** There are $52\choose7$ total hands. To subtract the ones that don't have pairs, minus ${13\choose7}\cdot4^7$

I don't understand why to subtract the ones that don't have pairs, we can't also do $52\times48\times44\times40\times36\times32\times28$ .. since there are 7 'slots' and once you pick a card with a certain rank you cannot choose another card of the same rank. So if you start with 52, once you pick a card you only have 48 choices left.

Comment: You are not wrong, though you need to take into account that the same hand can be dealt in several different orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "no pairs" hands:

- The first card can be any of $52$
- Given the first card's rank, the second card can be any of $48$
- Given the first two cards' ranks, the third card can be any of $44$
- ...
- Given the first six cards' ranks, the seventh card can be any of $28$
- But there are $7!$ possible orders of seven distinct cards

So you want to calculate $\frac{52 \times 48 \times 44 \times \cdots  \times 28}{7!}$ and taking out seven factors of $4$ gives  $\frac{13 \times 12 \times 11 \times \cdots  \times 7}{7!}\cdot 4^7$ which is $\displaystyle \frac{13!}{6!7!}\cdot 4^7 = {13\choose 7}\cdot 4^7.$